# Rest api to get list items not working when user's language is different

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-foundation

I have create a site in Chines and english language (LCID 1033) and having two users of different regional language.

Using rest api call to fetch list item based on title(site pages), is failing for Chinese language. Because site pages library is of different title.
How can i determine the library name for different language? i observed it is different in Chinese, french and english language.
How can i use the same code to fetch items for both sites?

Comment: There is a trivial way but is work with me create the two lists with English name after that  the list was created you can change the display name, But the internal name still the same.Good luck